# Script not running On Form Submit

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a script that creates a timestamp whenever a keyword is mentioned in the form response data sheet. I also set up a trigger to run whenever the form is submitted. When I submit the form it shows that the trigger ran and was completed, however it does not update the sheet unless I manually run the script. Is there a reason for this?
[trigger settings]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIsk8.png
[execution log]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivQgN.png

```
function onFormSubmit() { 
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Data Overview');
const sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName('Dewar ID');

if(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow(),sheet2.getLastColumn())
.getValue().toString().includes("Dewar1"))
{sheet4.getRange(3,4).setValue(new Date())};
}
```

Comment: Show execution Logs?

Comment: I have added a picture link of my execution log in my  question

Comment: Did you use the onFormSubmit trigger for the form or for the spreadsheet.  There are two triggers to choose from

Comment: From the event source dropdown I selected "From Spreadsheet" and from the event type dropdown I selected "on form submit".

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I tried it and it works for me

Comment: Check whether it returns Last row correctly. `console.log({r:sheet2.getLastRow(),c:sheet2.getLastColumn()})` and check the logs whether the row and column is correct. If not try using the form event object.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
function onMyFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));// you take a look at the event object
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh0 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  if (sh0.getRange(sh0.getLastRow(), sh0.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValue().includes("Dewar1")) { 
    sh1.getRange(3, 4).setValue(new Date()) };
}
```

It's almost the same thing  and it works fine

Here's a function to help you create the right type of trigger.  Perhaps you should change the name of the function and the trigger to something you have never used.

```
function createOnFormSubmitTriggerForSpreadsheet() {
  const ssid=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  const resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt("Create On Form Submit Trigger", "Enter Function Name", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(resp.getSelectedButton()==SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    let funcname=resp.getResponseText();
    if(!isTrigger(funcname)) {
      ScriptApp.newTrigger(funcname).forSpreadsheet(ssid).onFormSubmit().create();   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code works however, it seems to only work when I manually run the script.

Comment: It worked for me on an onFormSubmit  trigger.  There must be something wrong with you trigger. I'll add a function to help you create an onFormSubmit trigger.  I'm beginning to wonder if you don't have another onMyFormSubmit trigger because that is a problem. All of your functions must have a unique name.